BigQuery Change Data Capture with Storage Write API - _CHANGE_TYPE Column Not Found
Following this page, I'm trying to implement change data capture (CDC) in BigQuery using the Storage Write API. I'm including a _CHANGE_TYPE column in my data with values "UPSERT" and "DELETE", however, I'm getting the following error when streaming the data:
Saw unknown field error during proto message conversin within error messages{0=The source object has fields unknown to BigQuery: root._CHANGE_TYPE., 1=The source object has fields unknown to BigQuery: root

I'm using the default example for the Storage Write API from here with minor modifications -
  private static JSONObject buildRecord(int j) {
    JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
    record.put("id", String.valueOf(j));
    record.put("_timestamp", OffsetDateTime.now().toString());
    record.put("name", "sample_name");
    record.put("_CHANGE_TYPE", "UPSERT");
    return record;
  }

The same approach worked when working in Pub/Sub however when interacting directly with the write API directly it does not. What could be the case?

It might be, the _CHANGE_TYPE does not match between your JSON and the BQ table? Kindly check or you can define _CHANGE_TYPE in BigQuery
